# Saving figures using plt.savfig on Google Colab with axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, save, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to automatically save figures in my code using:

```html
from google.colab import files
plt.savefig("abc.png")
files.download("abc.png")
```

but when I download the figures, they are missing the lower half of the x-axis text, how do I keep it all? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
plt.savefig(<name>, bbox_inches = 'tight')
```

or try specifying a fixed size for your figure
and then save it.